# How to make multiple background images fill height of element

Tags: css, background-image

Mockup I'm trying to work towards [mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUG6P.png)

White box is the content and the gray boxes are multiple background images on the HTML element.

https://codepen.io/nikibrown/pen/KKVXMZb

I'm wondering if its possible to make multiple background images fill the entire height of an element. For example, I have 4 background images on the `html` element. I'd like them to take up 25% of the total height `html` element while also having the images 'cover' (which is why I used background-size: cover).

Is this possible with css? Wondering if I would have to do this with some javascript with `document.body.scrollHeight`  and sizing things that way.

Thanks in advance for your help! Much appreciated!

Comment: This looks doable for example see https://codyhouse.co/gem/alternate-fixed-scroll-backgrounds/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the css background: url(blahblabla) property, you would probably need to specify sections as seen in the link below. Each section would have its own background image, aka you'd need to write background for each section.

https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_section.asp

here is the only website that i can think of that uses sections..you can inspect the  web elements:

https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/